# Auth for NextJS with external token authed API

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js

I am new to NextJS, and I am integrating with an external server that supplies and then consumes auth tokens within the `Authorization` header (not JWTs, for what it's worth).

Option one would be to use client side data fetching for content that requires auth, and server side fetching for content that does not (which is about half of the content). In this scenario, requests that require auth would be made directly from the browser to the API, skipping the NextJS server entirely. This has the downside of not using the full extent of SSR, and of requiring the token to be stored in local storage or similar, which is not ideal.

Option two would be to use something like iron-session to store the token as an encrypted cookie on the client. The request flow would then be:

- Browser -> NextJS server, with cookie
- NextJS server -> API, with token extracted from cookie
- API -> NextJS server response
- NextJS to browser

This would allow for a stateless NextJS server, and allows for SSR. The downside being that all calls would have to be proxied through the NextJS server, even those that are done after page load (live updates, etc).

For the most part, I am fairly settled on the latter approach, but since I am new to NextJS, I am looking for a sense check on whether or not this makes sense.

Comment: Using Next.js for what it was designed for is the way to go: Fetching data on the server and minimizing client side code. I strongly recommend you take a look at [iron-session](https://github.com/vvo/iron-session) in combination with [server actions](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions).

Comment: @FabioNettis I mentioned iron-session in the question. Client side data fetching seems to be a top level feature in nextjs, so I do not agree that it is not 'using Next.js for what it was designed for'. Server side actions look interesting, but still seem to be an alpha feature.